# How to upload a single Image using Multer when req. file is always empty when testing with Postman?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer

I am trying to upload an image using multer and this is the code that I am just testing using Postman:

````
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

router.post('/uploadImage', upload.single('file'), (req,res)=>{
   console.log("Entering uploadImage Post")
   console.log("req.file contains:",req.file)
   res.status(204).end()
});

[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Servidor corriendo en puerto 5000
Connected to mongoDB...
Entering uploadImage Post
req.file contains: undefined```

This is the testing that I am doing in Postman:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So my problem is that the req.file is undefined , and I am not getting the images. Please check the following image


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS0CK.png
````

Answer (score 1):

I had to clear the headers, so I can obtain the `req.file`,

with this change it worked.